# Pandas - Reshape

Tags: python, pandas, transform, reshape

Can you help me to reshape a Pandas DataFrame from this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Clasif1': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 'PRE', 'POST'],
'Currency': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 'LC', 'USD'],
'Unnamed: 1': ['A','01/01/2018',1,7],
'Unnamed: 2': ['A','02/01/2018',2,8],
'Unnamed: 3': ['A','03/01/2018',3,9],
'Unnamed: 4': ['B','01/01/2018',4,10],
'Unnamed: 5': ['B','02/01/2018',5,11],
'Unnamed: 6': ['B','03/01/2018',6,12]
})
```

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G18LT.png)

To this:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
'Clasif1': ['PRE', 'POST','PRE', 'POST','PRE', 'POST','PRE', 'POST','PRE', 'POST','PRE', 'POST'],
'Currency': ['LC', 'USD','LC', 'USD','LC', 'USD','LC', 'USD','LC', 'USD','LC', 'USD'],
'A/B': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
'Date': ['01/01/2018','01/01/2018','02/01/2018','02/01/2018','03/01/2018','03/01/2018','01/01/2018','01/01/2018','02/01/2018','02/01/2018','03/01/2018','03/01/2018'],
'Value': [1,7,2,8,3,9,4,10,5,11,6,12]
})
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQRxr.png)

The result DataFrame rows order not needs necesary to match with the expected.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Could you post the input and output as tables in the text itself? It's hard to switch back and forth between the images. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditto, @Wen this is a very custom solution for your dataframe in this question:

```
colindx=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.iloc[0:2,2:].values)
df_out = df.iloc[2:,:].set_index(['Clasif1','Currency'])
df_out.columns = colindx
df_out.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['Clasif1','Currency'])
```

Output:

```
   Clasif1 Currency variable_0  variable_1 value
0      PRE       LC          A  01/01/2018     1
1     POST      USD          A  01/01/2018     7
2      PRE       LC          A  02/01/2018     2
3     POST      USD          A  02/01/2018     8
4      PRE       LC          A  03/01/2018     3
5     POST      USD          A  03/01/2018     9
6      PRE       LC          B  01/01/2018     4
7     POST      USD          B  01/01/2018    10
8      PRE       LC          B  02/01/2018     5
9     POST      USD          B  02/01/2018    11
10     PRE       LC          B  03/01/2018     6
11    POST      USD          B  03/01/2018    12
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, something like that I had in mind but I didn't know it how to handle two indexes in the DataFrame.

Comment: @CristianSaavedraDesmoineaux You're welcome.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like a customize solution , but if you can make sure the data is like this structure , you can using `stack`

```
s=df.iloc[:,2:].T.set_index([0,1]).stack()
s=s.to_frame('V').reset_index(level=[0,1])
s=s.join(df.iloc[:,:2]).sort_values([0,1])
s
Out[226]: 
   0           1   V Clasif1 Currency
2  A  01/01/2018   1     PRE       LC
3  A  01/01/2018   7    POST      USD
2  A  02/01/2018   2     PRE       LC
3  A  02/01/2018   8    POST      USD
2  A  03/01/2018   3     PRE       LC
3  A  03/01/2018   9    POST      USD
2  B  01/01/2018   4     PRE       LC
3  B  01/01/2018  10    POST      USD
2  B  02/01/2018   5     PRE       LC
3  B  02/01/2018  11    POST      USD
2  B  03/01/2018   6     PRE       LC
3  B  03/01/2018  12    POST      USD
```

Comment: Thanks @Wen, I choose the another one because It is more clear if another person read it. I am sure you are wright also.

Comment: @CristianSaavedraDesmoineaux no worry , happy coding